# Sorting an array of structures by a non-member of the struct

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

**Person** is a struct that contains 5 char arrays and nothing else.

**Score** is a float type number that I obtained from a function that uses some of Person fields to calculate it.

I don't wanna add score as a field in the *struct* **Person** for complicated reasons.

The goal is to print **Person**'s information (fields) based on how high the score is (from lowest to highest), in order to do that I made this struct to try to connect the score to its corresponding person.

```
typedef struct PersonWithAScore {
    Person* P;                    
    float score;
};
```

(also, is creating that struct even
the right thing to do? )

```
 PersonWithAScore *PersonScores = (PersonWithAScore*)malloc(number_of_scores*sizeof(PersonWithAScore));
       
// a for loop is happening here, so I can get all my scores and person(s) in that table, so that I start sorting them
       PersonScores[i].Person = &query;        // query is a Person type
       PersonScores[i].Score = match;      // match is what the score function returns
.
.      
.
// that is just a incomplete implementation I tried, you can just skip through and just read after the code

void swap(float *xp, float *yp)  // used in bubblesort
{  
   float temp = *xp;  
   *xp = *yp;  
   *yp = temp;  
}
void BubbleSort(PersonWithAScore* PWS, int n)    //n = number of scores
{                                                // void type? I might need to return an array (sorted)
 PersonWithAScore* Temp = PWS;
 int i, j;  
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)      
   for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)                  // m not so sure it's working, I didn't get to test it
       if (PWS[j].score > PWS[j+1].score)       
           swap(&PWS[j].score, &PWS[j+1].score);
 return 0;
}
```

So after that, I'm hoping to get a sorted array of scores (what initially was PersonScores[]) .
Optimally, I would want to go through the array while I'm printing out Person's information that are associated to each score, that is my first concern.

My second concern, is I'm not sure what sorting is proper in a big database (m currently working with a static database that contains a 100 of *Person*)

is it better to implement a quicksort algorithm in that case?
I figured it takes a lot of memory, but it is significantly faster than the bubble sort,
I'm trying to get a good balance of both speed and minimizing memory usage. Any ideas ?

Comment: You're only swapping the scores.  You want to swap full instances of `struct PersonWithAScore`.  Better yet, use `qsort`.

Comment: "is creating that struct even the right thing to do?" `PersonWithAScore` is very valid; it's kind of a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `qsort()` to sort the array of structures and recompute the scores on the fly in the comparison function:

```
float computePersonScore(Person *p) {
    /* compute the score from the person's data */
    ...
}

int compare_scores(const void *e1, const void *e2) {
    float f1 = computePersonScore(e1);
    float f2 = computePersonScore(e2);
    return (f1 > f2) - (f1 < f2);
}

...
    Person array[n];
    ...
    qsort(array, n, sizeof(*array), compare_scores);
...
```

If `computePersonScore()` needs a second argument, you can use `qsort_r` if your system supports it:

```
float computePersonScore(Person *p, Person *ref) {
    /* compute the score from the person's data */
    ...
}

int compare_scores(const void *e1, const void *e2, void *opaque) {
    float f1 = computePersonScore(e1, opaque);
    float f2 = computePersonScore(e2, opaque);
    return (f1 > f2) - (f1 < f2);
}

...
    Person array[n];
    Person *reference = ...;
    ...
    qsort_r(array, n, sizeof(*array), compare_scores, reference);
...
```

Comment: My `float computePersonScore(Person *record, Person *query)` takes two arguments, and I don't see a way of making `compare_scores` work..

Comment: If your system supports it, you could use `qsort_r()` and pass the second argument as the opaque argument, which in turn will be passed to the comparison function. Otherwise you could use a global variable so the compare function can pass it to `computePersonScore()`